# Indexing a list a variable amount of times, based on specified key

Tags: python

Let's say hypothetically you had a variable called `list_a`. Sometimes the objects inside are themselves also lists, so multiple indexing might be needed depending on what you want.

You have the following dictionary:

```
field_dict = {
    'name':[1],
    'birthdate':[2,5],
    'gender':[5,1,3]
}
```

Each value in the lists above represent how to index `list_a` to access the needed value.

To get a person's name, I just need to index `list_a` once, like this: `list_a[1]`.

To access their birthdate, I do `list_a[2][5]`. This is where the multiple indexing comes in. Likewise, to access gender, I do `list_a[5][1][3]`.

I wonder what the most elegant implementation of this would be - the only solutions I can think of would involve a bit of bruteforcing in the way of hard-coding some details excessively.

Comment: Consider using a list of objects with each object being details about a person.

Comment: Hypothetically I wouldn’t use a list of lists, I’d use a list of Person objects

Comment: I’m really curious what kind of data model leads to a three dimensional list of genders. That seems a little strange...sometimes the difficulty in coding a solution is a direct consequence of a bad data model. Maybe a refactor is worth thinking about?

Comment: That's just an example I cooked up to try and convey the matter, the question seemed interesting to ponder anyway because it never occurred me if indexing instructions could be saved as Python variables, as I've never done it before.

Comment: The duplicate I linked to asks about dictionaries, but it works pretty much the same with lists.

Comment: @Yeahprettymuch, it might be worth your time to look at numpy. You can index into multi-dimensional numpy arrays with tuples of indices, which would simplify the indexing aspect of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, this does not seem like a great data model.  But leaving that aside, I might implement the accessor like:

```
def get_item(obj, indices):
    if indices:
        return get_item(obj[indices[0]], indices[1:])
    else:
        return obj
```

or iteratively:

```
def get_item(obj, indices):
    while indices:
        obj = indices[0]
        indices = indices[1:]
    return obj
```